# Python Pandas find cell next to a known cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame 'df_img_pred' for the prediction result of some image processing algorithm

| Value A | Rate_A | Value B | Rate_B | Value C | Rate_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 0.9 | Bird | 0.2 | Fish | 0.1 |
| Tiger | 0.1 | Falcon | 0.8 | Whale | 0.25 |

For each row I want to select each max value and the corresponding value to it. so output shall be:

| Value | Rate |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | 0.9 |
| Falcon | 0.8 |

I've got a column with max value using  `df_img_pred[['Rate_A','Rate_B','Rate_C']].max(axis= 1)`
how can I get the corresponding value that its column is -1 of the index . What is the best practice for that without using loops?

Comment: Please modify the data frame structure for better understanding....

Comment: are you just looking for `df.shift(-1)`?

Comment: @GilseungAhn I've fixed the styling format

Comment: @noah No... shift just shift the whole column. or maybe I couldn't use it write. please share your thoughts about using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already calculated the `max_rates`, but you can use [**`idxmax`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get their column names:

```py
max_rates = df.filter(like='Rate').max(axis=1)
col_names = df.filter(like='Rate').idxmax(axis=1)

# 0    Rate_A
# 1    Rate_B
# dtype: object
```

Then if you [**`shift`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) the `df`, those same `col_names` columns will now contain the corresponding labels:

```py
max_values = df.shift(axis=1).apply(lambda row: row[col_names[row.name]], axis=1)

# 0       Dog
# 1    Falcon
# dtype: object
```

So then you can build the final result with `max_values` and `max_rates`:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'Value': max_values, 'Rates': max_rates})

#      Value   Rate
# 0      Dog    0.9
# 1   Falcon    0.8
```

Comment: Thank you that work with a great explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
max_colums = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == float].idxmax(axis=1)
max_labels = max_colums.apply(df.columns.get_loc) - 1

max_colums = iter(max_colums.values)
max_labels = iter(max_labels.values)

print(
    pd.DataFrame(
        df.apply(
            lambda x: {
                "Value": x[next(max_labels)],
                "Rate": x[next(max_colums)],
            },
            axis=1,
        ).tolist()
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
    Value  Rate
0     Dog   0.9
1  Falcon   0.8
```

Comment: so first line `max_colums = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == float].idxmax(axis=1)` will return the column name with the max value.  what the second line do? i have NaN values so it didn't work for me

Comment: @Karim Yes, it will return column indices with max value (in each row). max_labels will return indices of label columns (assuming they are ordered as in your question).

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["Dog", 0.9, "Bird", 0.2, "Fish", 0.1],
                 ["Tiger", 0.1, "Falcon", 0.8, "Whale", 0.25]],
                 columns = ["Value A", "Rate_A", "Value B", "Rate_B", "Value C", "Rate_C"])


val_df = df[['Value A', 'Value B', 'Value C']]
rate_df = df[['Rate_A', 'Rate_B', 'Rate_C']]

max_col_idx = rate_df.idxmax(axis = 1).replace({"Rate_A":0, "Rate_B":1, "Rate_C":2})
max_idx = [(i, max_col_idx.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(max_col_idx))]

val = [val_df.iloc[idx] for idx in max_idx]
rate = [rate_df.iloc[idx] for idx in max_idx]

result = pd.DataFrame({"Value":val, "rate":rate})
```

I think loop is essential for this problem... 
Anyway, it finds column index to maximize value for each row of rate_df by idxmax, and use them to select max value from val_df and rate_df.

Comment: I think there should be more efficent way as using match function in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are ordered, you can use [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the position of the max per row on the rate columns. then create a mask to extract this rate and corresponding value

```
# mask
m = np.arange(len(df)), np.argmax(df.filter(like='Rate').to_numpy(), axis=1)

res = pd.DataFrame({'value':df.filter(like='Value').to_numpy()[m],
                    'rate':df.filter(like='Rate').to_numpy()[m]})
print(res)
    value  rate
0     Dog   0.9
1  Falcon   0.8
```

Comment: can you please explain how your mask works?

Comment: @Karim so the `np.arange(len(df))` is for rw number and `np.argmax(df.filter(like='Rate').to_numpy(), axis=1)` is the position of the max in the columns Rate per row. At the end, ou end up with something similar to a list of couple (row, col) to extract the good column for each row. then you use this on the value and the rate columns separately